# original IP getting detected by server when using python requests but not when using curl

Tags: python, curl, proxy, python-requests

I am trying to send a request to this URL https://verify-email.org/home/verify-as-guest/example@example.com via a proxy server.

I obtained the proxy server here:
https://free-proxy-list.net/

The verify-email site has a limit of 5 emails verified per hour for free.

When I use a proxy server, I can bypass this limit if I keep changing the proxy servers. This works when I use curl:

```
curl --proxy http://IP:PORT https://verify-email.org/home/verify-as-guest/example@example.com
```

The above command works perfectly.

However when I do the same thing in python:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

def check_email(email):
    proxyDict = { 
                  "http"  : 'http://IP:PORT'
                }

    result = requests.get('https://verify-email.org/home/verify-as-guest/' + email, proxies=proxyDict, timeout=5).json()
    pprint(result)

check_email('example@example.com')
```

It doesn't work. It just gives me 5 tries and then stops working even if I change the IP which leads me to believe that there is a difference in the request sent by curl and the request sent by requests.

Is there any way I can get the same "curl" request in python-requests?

Comment: Pay for the service...‽ The prices are pretty affordable.

Comment: @deceze Actually I don't mind paying. I'm just trying to figure out why the requests library wasn't working.

Comment: Even for the above problem, I can think of a workaround by writing a shell script that uses curl and call that in the Python script, or just use subprocess to call curl directly. 
But I'm trying to understand why the requests are different.

I tried intercepting the requests generated using netcat:
Here's the one with curl:
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: *my host*
    User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
    Accept: */*

And here's the one with requests:

    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: * my host * 
    User-Agent: python-requests/2.13.0
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept: */*

Answer (score 0):

The `proxyDict` only contains a proxy to use for insecure http requests, but the service is using `https`.

Try

```
proxyDict = { 
    "http"  : 'http://IP:PORT',
    "https" : 'http://IP:PORT',
}
```